# should I put this information into the reference section or within the text?

Tags: publications, citations, writing-style

I am making an article about Information Technology, mainly related to policies, and I have a list of some solution providers with their proposals; something like this:

```
Vendor1, Proposal related to...
```

I would like to know if the web links that are related to each proposal can be put inside the same list or should I reference them, in some cases I have only web pages and in other pdfs. So should I do this:

```
Vendor1, Proposal related to ... (information available at http//nosense.com
Vendor2, Proposal related to ... (information available at http//page1/document1.pdf)
```

or like this:

```
Vendor1, Proposal related to ... [1]
Vendor2, Proposal.... [2]

References
[1] ...
[2] ...
```

which one should be the correct way of referencing this information?

Comment: Have you considered putting the urls in footnotes?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would put them in the bibliography, but either way looks fine, to me. I don't have a strong opinion, and I suggest you to do what you consider more readable.

However, I have often encountered copy editors who *did* have strong opinions on matters like this, so be ready to change it if they complain.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is long, you could put it in a table.  Otherwise giving the links in the text is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The weblinks can be put within the text. It is not a crime.